# How do i find a the version of which a github issue is fixed and released

Tags: kubernetes

For Example, i wanted to know which k8 version has the fix for  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23265/commits

From the commit history it shows that the change has been merged to 'master'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `git describe`

[`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) is intended for questions like yours.

- which tag is closest to the commit? (`git describe <sha>`)
- which tag contains commit? (`git describe <sha> --contains`)
- which branch or annotated tag is closest to the commit? (`git describe <sha>--all`)

## So, which k8 version has the fix for [PR 23265](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23265/commits) ?

Try these steps:

1. Copy to the clipboard SHA1 of the only commit of [PR 23265](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23265/commits): [2d064083001a7a7f7dfc8a5f8f2fc50582449bf6](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23265/commits/2d064083001a7a7f7dfc8a5f8f2fc50582449bf6)
2. Clone `k8s` source: `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/`
3. `cd kubernetes`
4. Get the earliest annotated tag that contains commit:

```
git describe 2d064083001a7a7f7dfc8a5f8f2fc50582449bf6 --contains
v1.4.0-alpha.3~307^2
```

Voila, at least [`v1.4.0-alpha.3`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.4.0-alpha.3) contains [PR 23265](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23265/commits)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the commit page https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/23265/commits/2d064083001a7a7f7dfc8a5f8f2fc50582449bf6

[image]

It's right there in light grey v1.4.0-alpha.3. You can see all the tags from all the versions the commit is in.