# Starting minikube in ec2 shows "X Sorry, Kubernetes v1.18.0 requires conntrack to be installed in root's path"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to start Minikube, so I ran

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

But it shows in the console the below lines:

> minikube v1.9.2 on Amazon 2 (Xen/amd64)
> Using the none driver based on user configuration
> X Sorry, Kubernetes v1.18.0 requires conntrack to be installed in root's path

Note that I have installed `kubectl minikube` and `docker`.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue. Install 'conntrack' with

```
sudo apt install conntrack
```

Then continue to start your minikube:

```
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Answer (score 7):

Execute following commands

`yum install conntrack`
start minikube as root
`start --driver=none`

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR : update `minkikube`

You need `minkikube` not older than `v1.9.0-beta`

### It's a known issue

There is a [known issue #7179](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7179) reproduced in `1.18`

Fixed in [Pull Request #7180](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/7180), the latest commit is [1273d4f](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/7180/commits/1273d4f8e756ac5eca89d94c449450fb2da21a5a):

> install conntrack for github action integration tests #7180

Minimal `minikube` ver that contain commit [1273d4f](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/7180/commits/1273d4f8e756ac5eca89d94c449450fb2da21a5a) is `v1.9.0-beta`:

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/
cd minikube
git describe 1273d4f8e756ac5eca89d94c449450fb2da21a5a
>v1.9.0-beta.2-16-g1273d4f8e
```

### Explanation of `git describe`

Explanation of `git describe` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60120621/5720818)

[The command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) is useful for cases such as:

> - which tag is closest to the commit? (`git describe <sha>`)
> - which tag contains commit? (`git describe <sha> --contains`)
> - which branch or annotated tag is closest to the commit? (`git describe <sha>--all`)

Comment: Is there an easy way to upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 7, run following command:

```
yum install conntrack
```

And don't forget to have at least 2 (v)CPUs

Answer (score 2):

You need to install conntrack:

```
apt-get install conntrack -y
```

and then you can run the minikube start command again

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

make sure you do it as a root user or prefix sudo.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are running on Azure or AWS, use

```
minikube start --force
```

instead of

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Answer (score 0):

If your running ubuntu, make sure you systemd and kubeadm already installed. I found that this resolved for me

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
at <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Reference Links:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-
 https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to resolve the issue:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=docker
```