# Minikube Installation Error on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, minikube

I am executing command:

```
[root@ip-172-31-15-218 ~]# minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

ENV specification:

- minikube v1.13.0 on Amazon 2 (xen/amd64)
- Using the none driver based on user configuration

I am getting an error:

```
X Exiting due to GUEST_MISSING_CONNTRACK: Sorry, Kubernetes 1.19.0 requires conntrack to be installed in root's path
```

How to install conntrack? Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Run following command:

```
$ yum install conntrack
```

Don't forget to have at least 2 (v)CPUs.
If you don't have [yum](https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) installed - execute [commands](https://low-orbit.net/how-to-install-yum-on-ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt update -y 
$ sudo apt install -y yum-utils
```

and then install conntrack.

Then you can simply run command:

```
$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Take a look: [c2-shows-x-sorry-kubernetes-requires-conntrac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238136/cant-start-minikube-in-ec2-shows-x-sorry-kubernetes-v1-18-0-requires-conntrac),  [conntrack-manual](https://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html#introduction).